# Reliably polyfilling `navigator.userActivation.hasBeenActive`?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, polyfills

[`navigator.userActivation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UserActivation) is apparently still unavailable in Firefox according to MDN, and has only just been added to Safari. I'm wondering if there's a simple way to polyfill it that I'm neglecting. I was originally using a window `click` event, but click events can be triggered by JS code, so that approach is unreliable.

I'd like the code to be fairly robust, but to be clear it does *not* need to guard against *malicious* attempts to subvert/fool the activation detection.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I just learned about `e.isTrusted`, which is only true for "real" clicks, so that seems like a pretty good solution:

```js
if(!navigator.userActivation) {
  navigator.userActivation = {hasBeenActive:false};
  let pageActivationClickHandler = (e) => {
    if(e.isTrusted) {
      navigator.userActivation.hasBeenActive = true;
      window.removeEventListener("click", pageActivationClickHandler);
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener("click", pageActivationClickHandler);
}
```